# AlloyUI Diagram Builder: Connect nodes by ID instead of name

Tags: javascript, jquery, liferay, yui, alloy-ui

I am currently creating an AlloyUI Diagram Builder from data in a database.

Everything works perfect except that nodes can only be connected by their names.
The issue is that I will have nodes with the same names which I still need to be separate nodes.
When I now connect those nodes using connectAll() the wrong nodes get connected.

Is there any way to connect the nodes by their ID ?

Best regards,

Daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem, I add a new attribute called "databaseid" and now I can move different nodes with the same name. but I still have the problem to connect the nodes. 
I'm thinking in change the connectAll function using my new attribute, or to gave them ghost names to connect.
Let me know if you find a better solution.

Marcelo

Comment: I will start with adding a custom property and then I will try to change the connectAll method ... will keep you posted ...